# PHP warning "Warning: Declaration of CRM_Mailchimp_Permission" logged when open a CiviReport

Tags: civireport

Drupal 7.67
Civi 5.13.4

I get a PHP warning in my Drupal logs every time I open a report in Civi. The complete warning is 
Warning: Declaration of CRM_Mailchimp_Permission::check($permissions) should be compatible with CRM_Core_Permission::check($permissions, $contactId = NULL) in require_once() (line 218 of ...modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/ClassLoader.php).

I do not get any php errors with Inspect Console on the report pages.

I looked at the permissions and I have all MailChimp related items checked for my role.

I looked in the CiviCRM View Log and I do not see anything there related to Mailchimp. There is however this log repeatedly. Not sure if it is related.
warning] Deprecated Path: There is a setting (generate_schema_and_data) not correctly defined. You may see unpredictability due to this. CRM_Core_Setting::setItems

Any ideas what might case this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is already a [fix](https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mailchimp/pull/320/files) submitted for this warning but haven't got merged. But i believe the fix should fix the problem. Can you try after applying patch from [here](https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mailchimp/pull/320.patch)?

Cheers

Pradeep

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it